# Make [db2i] a synonym of [db2-400]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

These two tags exist simply because of IBM's need to rename products. DB2/400 is the same product as DB2 for i, though DB2 for i is a newer release, it is the same database product. The name change matches name changes for AS/400, iSeries, System i, IBM i on Power. It also follows the name changes for the OS of OS/400, i5/OS, IBM i. These need to be synonyms, but the synonym request has sat out there long enough that maybe a moderator needs to do it. Since DB2400 has the most questions, it probably should be the main tag, and DB2I the synonym.

[db2400] was just renamed to [db2-400]. Can we get a moderator to add [db2i] as a synonym to [db2-400].

Comment: I just successfully lobbied for the renaming of [tag:db2400] to [tag:db2-400]. In light of that, I was going to edit this question, but now I'm wondering whether to also ask for renaming [tag:db2i] to [tag:db2-i] while we're at it. Granted, `db2i` is not nearly as bad as `db2400` but maybe the consistency with other db2-whatevers is worth it.

Comment: Where did that happen? We need to get db2i made a synonym or db2-400 so that it's questions get merged with db2-400. As it stands, the questions are nearly all added to db2-400, and the ones put in db2i are missed until someone wanders over to that tag.

Comment: Well, my tag renaming request was [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364060/please-rename-tag-db2400-to-db2-400). I agree with the premise of your synonym request, but moderator attention isn't always easy to come by, so I was wondering if it would be worth asking for renaming *as well as* synonymizing.

Comment: Looks like the renaming just created a new db2-400 tag, and added db2400 as a synonym. Maybe we should ask for db2i to be a synonym of db2-400 and be done with that.