# Please rename tag [db2400] to [db2-400]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The tag as it currently stands just looks wrong. There is plenty of precedent for the general convention of using a hyphen in the tag name when it would improve readability or appearance, and in particular we already have [db2-luw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db2-luw), which is the same database product but for a different platform.

Even the first seven characters in both the [db2400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db2400) wiki entry and usage excerpt are (as of this writing) `DB2-400`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick action! Would it be similarly simple to address [this related tag request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358503/make-db2i-a-synonym-of-db2-400)?